# How can I prevent javascript from copying a line break to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, line-breaks

I found a program that allows me to copy data from a div to the clipboard. When copied, it adds a line break even though there's no line break in my div.  How can I remove any line breaks from the copy.

```js
  function copyDivToClipboard(elem) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(elem));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>This is a test</div>

<button onclick='copyDivToClipboard("test")'>Copy to clipboard</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of  `range.selectNode` use `range.selectNodeContents`

```js
function copyDivToClipboard(elem) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById(elem));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  This is a test
</div>

<button onclick='copyDivToClipboard("test")'>Copy to clipboard</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` element you are copying contains the newline as part of its text content when Javascript is copying it. If you instead use a `span` you will not get the newline with the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/sLv9ux50/

Comment: That does work, thank you.    Just curious though, if I insisted on using DIV, is there a way to remove the newline at the end when it copies?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a fallback to `document.selection` and a callback function to execute once it's done.

```js
function copy_to_clipboard (containerid = '', cb = () => {}) {
    if (document.selection) {
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
      range.select().createTextRange();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      cb();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      var range = document.createRange();
      var node = document.getElementById(containerid);
      range.selectNodeContents(node);
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      cb();
    }
  }
```